# Is "without" a preposition or an adverb in "She left the hotel without paying the bill"?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

> She left the hotel **without** paying the bill.

How do I tell if a particular word is a preposition or an adverb when it is attached to a verb?

Comment: How is it "attached to a verb"? Just because it is positioned next to something that looks like a verb? There is essentially no big difference between _without paying the bill_ or _without her luggage_. What would you say _without_ is in _without her luggage_? Surely not an _adjective_ because it is attached to a noun?

Comment: It's tempting to see *She left without delay* as "adverbial", since it answers the question *How did she leave?* But I honestly wonder what good it does learners to agonize over POS categories for such usages. I speak perfectly good English without knowing (or really caring).

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's important because many Learners (NS and NNS) are taught that prepositions employed without objects, particularly in what are called "phrasal" verbs, are adverbs, and it's not always easy for NNS to distinguish whether a given preposition in these constructions has an object or not.

Comment: @StoneyB: Even armed with all that, I'm none the wiser as to whether OP's ***without*** is really a preposition or an adverb. Nor do I know whether it would be the same with a (*very* old-fashioned) butler announcing *There is a gentleman caller without, ma'am* (as opposed to *...a gentleman caller without an appointment*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is why I like *CGEL*'s treatment of these as *intransitive prepositions* -- you can treat the *without* in "a caller is without" as a locative preposition phrase just like "in the drawing room".

Comment: @StoneyB: I get that one. But *without an appointment* seems significantly different. Is that also prepositional, or have we now moved into *adverbial* territory?

Comment: @FumbleFingers The word *without* is a preposition in both cases; the function of the PP is "adjectival" in both cases. It's definitely attributive in "caller without an appointment", opinions differ about whether it's attributive or predicative with the existential *there is* construction. In OP's example traditional grammar would take *without paying* as an adverbial; I would regard it as a "secondary predication", like *naked* in "He sleeps naked".

Comment: @StoneyB: Ah, right. Here's [an interesting snippet of info](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4y3nBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=%22left+without+paying%22+adverb+vs+preposition&source=bl&ots=agatC6Gxc6&sig=Njx-7uqUENXx4GhwOG0GbzU5W4M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cgReVaqaEcfaUb38gcAP&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22left%20without%20paying%22%20adverb%20vs%20preposition&f=false) I just found which may be relevant to NNS. Apparently in Swedish, among other languages, the "literal" translation of *He left without paying the bill* uses the infinitive - effectively, *He left without **to pay** the bill*. Tricky!

Answer (score 1):

*Without* is a preposition.

*Paying* is not a verb, but a verbal.  The entire phrase *paying the bill* I believe technically functions as a noun phrase.

*Without paying the bill* doesn't really answer the question "How did she leave?" so it's not adverbial.  *Without paying the bill* does not really have anything to do with the *manner* or *way* (this is what *how* means) in which she left - it describes an additional and separate idea (it's more of a *what*).  She left AND she didn't pay the bill - she didn't leave in manner or way that obstructed her from paying the bill.

Comment: Let me get this straight. You say *without paying* is a preposition usage because it doesn't describe the *manner* in which she left. Are you by implication saying that *without delay* is adverbial (because it does describe the manner)? Even more relevant, perhaps, what about *without waking me*, which it seems to me is even more definitely a description of *how* she went.

Comment: No, it's a description of something that didn't happen while something else was happening.  It's a *what*, not a *how*.  It can *imply* a manner, but is not itself a manner.

Comment: I'm afraid your distinction is too subtle for me. I could buy *She left without anyone noticing* as meaning nobody noticed *while* she was leaving, so you could rephrase it as two consecutive statements *She left. Nobody noticed her departure*. But that doesn't seem to work so well with *She left. Her departure was without delay*, since the act of leaving and the absence of any delay seem to be inherently part of a single action being more fully described (*adverbially*, I'd have thought). How would you deconstruct, say, *I spoke without thinking* ?

Comment: It's hard to explain.  I could be wrong and I'm eager for further insight myself.  :)  Deconstruction ... You spoke *and* you didn't think *while/before* you spoke.  She left the hotel *and* didn't pay the bill *while she was leaving/before she left* the hotel.  Something like e.g. "She left the hotel unwillingly" doesn't fit that.  She left the hotel in and the activity of her leaving was in a state of unwillingness.

Comment: Well, even given [StoneyB's helpful pointer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/57330/is-without-a-preposition-or-an-adverb-in-she-left-the-hotel-without-paying-th/57339?noredirect=1#comment109044_57330), I can't really see how being able to categorise ***without*** as a preposition or an adverb would help anyone learn how to learn English. I'd just assume all the *without X* constructions we've been considering here are "adverbial phrases", within which the actual word ***without*** is a preposition, but I still don't see what difference it makes what we call these components.